# How to achieve selenium zimbra title python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Good morning,

I created an appointment on Zimbra and I would like to be able to search for it with its title containing permanent so that I can click on it.
Attached are some items.

```
<td class="appt_30_name" style="white-space:nowrap;">test du jour</td>

/html/body/div[3]/div[10]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div[18]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]
```

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay and I found my mistake. The class differs between the creating user.
In concrete terms
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'appt_30_new_name') and contains(text(), 'permanent')]")
And
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'appt_new_name') and contains(text(), '%s')]" % word)

Zimbra calendar is not nice :)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information provided and assuming below is the HTML of the desired element,

```
<td class="appt_30_name" style="white-space:nowrap;">test du jour</td>
```

You can use below relative XPath expression to locate the element:

```
//td[text()='test du jour']
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the text 'permanent' is in an element `class="appt_30_name"`, then maybe this is what you should try

`//td[contains(@class, 'appt_30_name') and contains(text(), 'permanent')]`

you may replace the `class` name `appt_30_name' or text value` permanent` with the ones you are attempting to hook up.

Please tell me if it works for you.